# SQLite Select command in bash

Tags: sql

I'm having trouble with my SQLite Select called from a bash script. I'm trying to get a single value from myDB.db and store it to the variable "result".

> result=`sqlite3 /media/0CBA-1996/logfiles/SQLite3Database/myDB.db "SELECT energy FROM SmartMeter WHERE Timestamp= date('now') LIMIT 1"`;
>
> echo $result

The problem seems to be with the quotations cause when I leave out "WHERE Timestamp= date('now')" I get a return from the database.

Any ideas ?
Thanks
Mick

Comment: if it was the quotes, then a simple `select date('now')` would also fail.

Answer (score 8):

normally you want the OUTPUT to become the variables value:

```
result=$(sqlite3 /media/0CBA-1996/logfiles/SQLite3Database/myDB.db "SELECT energy FROM SmartMeter WHERE Timestamp= date('now') LIMIT 1")

echo $result
```

you nee to use $() or `` like this

```
result=`sqlite3 /media/0CBA-1996/logfiles/SQLite3Database/myDB.db "SELECT energy FROM SmartMeter WHERE Timestamp= date('now') LIMIT 1" `

echo $result
```